# PHP script works on my local pc but not on my server

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP script, to take the data enter on a form and store it in mysql database. When I run it on my PC it enters the data correctly, but, when I run it from my online server it display my PHP script on a new page!

Here is my code:

---

```
 <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "theuser";
    $password = "thepassword";
    $dbname = "thedb";

    $cName['c_name'] = isset($_POST['c_name']);

    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    // set the PDO error mode to exception

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO the_tb (c_name,c_reg,c_tel1,c_tel2,f_name,l_name,m_tel,email_addr1,email_addr2,p_addr1,p_addr2,p_city,p_county,p_code,p_country,contact_message,yes_no) VALUES ('$_POST[c_name]','$_POST[c_reg]','$_POST[c_tel1]','$_POST[c_tel2]','$_POST[f_name]','$_POST[l_name]','$_POST[m_tel]','$_POST[email_addr1]','$_POST[email_addr2]','$_POST[p_addr1]','$_POST[p_addr2]','$_POST[p_city]','$_POST[p_county]','$_POST[p_code]','$_POST[p_country]','$_POST[contact_message]','$_POST[yes_no]')";

    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);

    echo "'$_POST[c_name]','$_POST[c_reg]','$_POST[c_tel1]','$_POST[c_tel2]','$_POST[f_name]','$_POST[l_name]','$_POST[email_addr1]','$_POST[email_addr2]','$_POST[p_addr1]','$_POST[p_addr2]','$_POST[p_city]','$_POST[p_county]','$_POST[p_code]','$_POST[p_country]','$_POST[contact_message]','$_POST[yes_no]'.";

        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }

    $conn = null;
?>
```

---

As I said it works on my local workstation. Now I have checked that I have the same version on PHP installed as well as all the relevant modules and all seem to be the same.

I know that I have made a mistake somewhere but for the life of me I cannot see where. Could one you guys PHP expert can tell me where I went wrong?

Thank you kindly

Comment: `$servername = "localhost";` is wrong. `$username = "swwdbadmin";
$password = "T67yur50GK#$";
$dbname = "soluteldb";` is probably different too.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).